# Array as function parameter

Tags: javascript

This snippet plays with array of names. The last part should return the biggest name in array (by length). It returns 0..
I suspect it has to do with passing array "names" as function parameter..
Thanks.

```js
var names = ["John", "Melissa", "Bob", "That guy with strange name"];
var j = 0;

function test(name) {
  return console.log(name + " name's length is " + name.length);
}

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  test(names[i]);
  if (names[i].length > 5) {
    console.log("here is name that has  more than 5 characters in it! -" + names[i] + '\n');
    j++;
  }
}

console.log("Amount of names that are bigger than 5 char. in array is " + j + '\n');

function findmax(array) {
  var max = 0;
  var a = array.length;
  for (var counter = 0; counter < a; counter++) {
    if (array[counter].length > max.length) {
      max = array[counter];
    }
  }
  return console.log("the largest name is " + max);
}

findmax(names);
```

Comment: Why are you returning `console.log()`?

Comment: To print the result wrapped in sentence.

Comment: Then just use `console.log`. Dont use `return console.log()`

Comment: Otherwise the result is not printed when function is called.

Comment: Use `console.log(...)` to print followed by `return max`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `findmax` function, your condition is

```
if (array[counter].length > max.length)
```

Your max is initialised with 0 which is a number so `number.length` is `undefined`.

Now comparing any value with `undefined` will return `false`. So your max is never changed.

Try initialising it to `""`

```js
var names = ["John", "Melissa", "Bob", "That guy with strange name"];
var j = 0;

function test(name) {
  return console.log(name + " name's length is " + name.length);
}

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  test(names[i]);
  if (names[i].length > 5) {
    console.log("here is name that has  more than 5 characters in it! -" + names[i] + '\n');
    j++;
  }
}

console.log("Amount of names that are bigger than 5 char. in array is " + j + '\n');

function findmax(array) {
  var max = "";
  var a = array.length;
  for (var counter = 0; counter < a; counter++) {
    if (array[counter].length > max.length) {
      max = array[counter];
    }
  }
  return console.log("the largest name is " + max);
}

findmax(names);
```

Comment: I have updated you answer. Please revert it if not required.

Answer (score 1):

I just wonder, `"That guy with strange name"` is a name?

```js
var names = ["John", "Melissa", "Bob"];

function findmax(arr) {
  var max = 0;
  var word = '';
  names.forEach(function(v){
    if (v.length > max) {
      max = v.length;
      word = v;
    }
  });
  console.log(`The longest element is '${word}' with ${max} letters.`);
}

findmax(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `var max = 0;` with `var max = "";` because you're are using `max.length` for comparison which expects `max` to be a string, not number.

Comment: And **why** would you do that?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just change `max=0` to `max=''` as length property is only for Strings and not for numbers.

```
max=0; //max.length -> undefined
max=''; // max.lenght -> 0
```

```js
var names = ["John", "Melissa", "Bob", "That guy with strange name"];
var j = 0;

function test(name) {
    return console.log(name + " name's length is " + name.length);
}

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    test(names[i]);
    if (names[i].length > 5) {
        console.log("here is name that has  more than 5 characters in it! -" + names[i] + '\n');
        j++;
    }
}

console.log("Amount of names that are bigger than 5 char. in array is " + j + '\n');

function findmax(array) {
    var max = '';
    var a = array.length;
    for (var counter = 0; counter < a; counter++) {
        if (array[counter].length > max.length) {
            max = array[counter];
        }
    }
    return console.log("the largest name is " + max);
}

findmax(names);
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `max=""` and not `"0"`

Comment: changed. first I put it just to make the user understand with length 1. Agree with you. Putting "" is better than putting a dumb value

Comment: If `max` is "2" then its length will be one.  Even with the name Melissa, the length of "7" is still one.  Just use `max` instead of `max.length`.  No need to arbitrarily make it a string

Comment: he uses this statement `max = array[counter];`,  so the value of max will be updated with name(string). so I think max.value is right

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be returning a console.log. Instead, you should return the largest name and put the text in the console.log.

```
function findmax(array) {
//code
return max;
};

console.log("the largest name is " + findmax(names));
```